# How to send email to a particular email address using PHP?

Tags: php, email

I tried to do:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['yourname'];
$email = $_POST["youremail"];
$message = $_POST["yourmessage"];
$to = "memexamples@gmail.com";
$subject = "messages";
mail($to, $subject, $message,$email);
?>
```

And failed? What am I doing wrong? I am trying on live host - Cpanel

Comment: Your headers parameter (4th argument) is wrong, see http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: What's the `$email` variable? `mail()` only requires `to`, `subject` and `message`. It has optional `headers` and `parameters` as additional arguments, but those require specific formatting (including carriage returns, which probably aren't in your `$_POST`).

Comment: See example #2 in the docs, more specifically (maybe you should have done that before asking here, actually)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem a few times, and for me this seems to do the trick.

```
mail($to, "From: ".$email, "$subject", $message);
```

Adding the `"From: "` and the quotes around subject for whatever reason make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort  ..but it does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```html
**try this** 

mail($to, $subject,$message,$headers)

$to=.....@...;
$subject="Contact Details";
$message='<h3>Hai</h3>';
$message.='<h4>Welcome</h4>';
$headers="Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
```